# Getting Error: HttpError: Resource not accessible by integration when using actions-ecosystem/action-create-issue

Tags: github-actions

In GitHub Actions, I was testing the `actions-ecosystem/action-create-issue` action.

This action creates an automatic github-issue.

But the action crashed, I kept getting this error:

[image]

The workflow yaml file that triggered this error (and can be used to reproduce it) was this code:

```
name: Deploy to foo
on:
 push:
   branches: [develop]

jobs:
  deploy-to-staging:
  name: Deploy to Staging

permissions:
  contents: 'read'
  id-token: 'write'

runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - name: Create deploy issue
    uses: actions-ecosystem/action-create-issue@v1
    with:
      github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
      title: Hello World 
      body: |
        ## Deployed to Staging Server

        - [ ] Task-1
        - [ ] Task-2
      labels: |
        deploy
        staging
```

Answer (score 4):

From a lot of search on the web I couldn't find the answer, most resources associated this error with the github token.

During my trial and error I noticed that commenting out the whole `permissions:` property fixed the error and an automatic-GitHub-issue was created **BUT** I did need those permissions for additional actions in my workflow so deleting the `permissions:` property was not a solution for me.

Researching the GitHub documentation I saw that there was a special permission key named `issues`, when I added it to the `permissions:` property with a value of `write` it solved the error.

The code for the fix is :

```
name: Deploy to foo
on:
 push:
   branches: [develop]

jobs:
  deploy-to-staging:
  name: Deploy to Staging

permissions:
  contents: 'read'
  id-token: 'write'
  issues: 'write' #__This fixed the HttpError: Resource not accessible by integration

runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
  - name: Create deploy issue
    uses: actions-ecosystem/action-create-issue@v1
    with:
      github_token: ${{ secrets.github_token }}
      title: Hello World 
      body: |
        ## Deployed to Staging Server

        - [ ] Task-1
        - [ ] Task-2
      labels: |
        deploy
        staging
```

The gitHub documentation that I used for research was:
[GitHub Actions: Control permissions for GITHUB_TOKEN](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-20-github-actions-control-permissions-for-github_token/#:%7E:text=GitHub%20Actions%20now%20lets%20you,token%20when%20a%20job%20completes.)

Answer (score 1):

This is settings related issue as far above error is concerned in question.

1. Go to repository "Settings".
2. After that it will show you a left pane where you will find "Actions"
3. Expand "Actions" tab
4. Click on "General" under options tab.
5. Now on new page scroll down and you will fine "Workflow Permissions"
6. Select "Read and Write" under "Workflow Permissions".

Rest of your settings seems fine as no more bug reported by you. If problem persists let me know I will fix it. I couldn't re-create HTTP error but I guess the solution will resolve both.